# Force full redraw of a Jpanel Java2D

Tags: java, swing, awt, graphics2d, java-2d

My question is that i need to make a GUI that keeps updating becuse i get values that can change from a DB and i got some problems in the graphical area.

well im using Drawline and Drawstring from Graphics2D that print values that are found on the database, this strings and lines move and change value, so i need to call repaint(); with a timer to make them apper in the jpanel, the problem is that repaint(); is not removing the old painting in the background before painting, but when i resize all updates perfecly.

i know a way to clear but the background color goes away too so,
There is a way to update the jpanel removing old paintings and keep the deafult background color?

Not updated
[image: perfect]

After changing a coordenate and a label text to "AXIS Y" (repaint called automatically from a timer)
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you're forgetting to call `super.paintComponent`. For better help, [post an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @peeskillet Your comment should be an answer. I agree with you on that one.

Comment: Yep, what @peeskillet says is the truth. More importantly, how can we know for sure what you're doing wrong without code? You can improve this question greatly.

Comment: @karlphillip without seeing some code, it's just an educated guess

Comment: @peeskillet See! You got it right. +1 to your crystal ball.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer my code is quite long now, and there is a lot of variables that comes from every side of the program, at first i thought at sending the paintcomponent but probably would not run.

Comment: Ollegn, please read Mad's link before replying. He's not asking for you to post your whole code. Rather if you have similar questions, you will want to create a new program, one that is quite small, compiles, runs, and demos your problem and that's it. Otherwise we're reduced to guessing, and while ppskillet guessed right today, that's the exception not the rule. Again, your question could be improved on.

Comment: I think that what everybody else is saying is that in the future, would be best to share a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/). Not all of us carry a crystal ball around like @peeskillet

Comment: @Ollegn See that part where it says *"runnable example which demonstrates"* - This doesn't mean all you code, just an example which replicates your work flow which is runnable by others...otherwise all you will get is guess work...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the looks of your image, it looks like you're just forgetting to call `super.paintComponent` in the `paintComponent` method. What this does is repaint the background for you, so aren't left with the previous paint artifacts.

```
@Override
protected voud paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
}
```

Note: For future reference, though the images gave us a good picture, it always best to post  [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with those images, so we *don't* have to make guesses (educated or not)