# How do I start an animation (move a circle from one point to another) in a JPanel from a class that extends thread?

Tags: java, swing, animation

I have a class called Player that extends thread, its parameter is a `JPanel` (called `DrawPanel`) and the coordinates x, y;
in the `Player` constructor I draw a circle in position x, y on the panel
(I don't know how correct it is).

In the `Player` run function, I would like to start an animation that moves a small red circle from the player coordinates to an other point.

like in this animation.

[image]

How can I do this?

```
public class Player extends Thread {
 private  Graphics graphic;
 private Graphics2D g2;
 private int x;
 private int y;
 private DrawPanel panel;
    public Player(int x, int y,DrawPanel panel) 
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.panel = panel;
        graphic = panel.getGraphics();
        g2 = (Graphics2D) graphic;
        g2.fillOval( column,row, 10, 10);
    }
    public void run()
    {
     //startAnimation(this.x,this.y,destination.x,destination.y)
    }
}
```

Comment: `getGraphics` is a bad idea and not how custom paint in Swing should be done. Swing is also NOT thread safe, so you should not update the ui or the state the ui relies on from outside the context of the event dispatching thread.

Comment: A better solution might involve a Swing `Timer`, which would call a “update” method on the panel, so the panel could update its internal state, and then call `repaint` (directly or indirectly) on the panel, which would trigger a new paint pass, then in the panel’s `paintComponent` method, you would paint the panels current state

Comment: [As an over arching conceptual example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078835/i-am-trying-to-make-ball-gradually-move/15079240?r=SearchResults#15079240)

Comment: I would also recommend having a read through [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html), [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html), [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: thanks,  I'll read everything and then I'll try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just want to start with, animation is not easy and good animation is hard.  There is a lot of theory that goes into making animation "look" good, which I'm not going to cover here, there are better people and resources for that.

What I am going to discuss is how you can do "good" animation in Swing at a basic level.

The first problem seems to be the fact that you don't have a good understanding of how painting works in Swing. You should start by reading [Performing Custom Painting in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Next, you don't seem to realise that Swing is actually NOT thread safe (and is single threaded).  This means you should never update the UI or any state the UI relies on from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details.

The simplest solution to solving this problem is to use a Swing `Timer`, see [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details.

Now, you could simply run a `Timer` and do a straight, linear progression until all your points meet their target, but this is not always the best solution, as it doesn't scale well and will appear different on different PC's, based on there individual capabilities.

In most cases, a duration based animation gives a better result.  This allows the algorithm to "drop" frames when the PC is unable to keep up.  It scales much better (of time and distance) and can be highly configurable.

I like to produce re-usable blocks of code, so I will start with a simple "duration based animation engine"...

```
// Self contained, duration based, animation engine...
public class AnimationEngine {

    private Instant startTime;
    private Duration duration;

    private Timer timer;

    private AnimationEngineListener listener;

    public AnimationEngine(Duration duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public void start() {
        if (timer != null) {
            return;
        }
        startTime = null;
        timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                tick();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        timer.stop();
        timer = null;
        startTime = null;
    }

    public void setListener(AnimationEngineListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public AnimationEngineListener getListener() {
        return listener;
    }

    public Duration getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public double getRawProgress() {
        if (startTime == null) {
            return 0.0;
        }
        Duration duration = getDuration();
        Duration runningTime = Duration.between(startTime, Instant.now());
        double progress = (runningTime.toMillis() / (double) duration.toMillis());

        return Math.min(1.0, Math.max(0.0, progress));
    }

    protected void tick() {
        if (startTime == null) {
            startTime = Instant.now();
        }
        double rawProgress = getRawProgress();
        if (rawProgress >= 1.0) {
            rawProgress = 1.0;
        }

        AnimationEngineListener listener = getListener();
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.animationEngineTicked(this, rawProgress);
        }

        // This is done so if you wish to expand the 
        // animation listener to include start/stop events
        // this won't interfer with the tick event
        if (rawProgress >= 1.0) {
            rawProgress = 1.0;
            stop();
        }
    }

    public static interface AnimationEngineListener {

        public void animationEngineTicked(AnimationEngine source, double progress);
    }
}
```

It's not overly complicated, it has a `duration` of time, over which it will run.  It will `tick` at a regular interval (of no less then 5 milliseconds) and will generate `tick` events, reporting the current progression of the animation (as a normalised value of between 0 and 1).

The idea here is we decouple the "engine" from those elements which are using it.  This allows us to use it for a much wider range of possibilities.

Next, I need some way to keep track of the position of my moving object...

```
public class Ping {

    private Point point;
    private Point from;
    private Point to;
    private Color fillColor;

    private Shape dot;

    public Ping(Point from, Point to, Color fillColor) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.fillColor = fillColor;
        point = new Point(from);

        dot = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 6, 6);
    }

    public void paint(Container parent, Graphics2D g2d) {
        Graphics2D copy = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();
        int width = dot.getBounds().width / 2;
        int height = dot.getBounds().height / 2;
        copy.translate(point.x - width, point.y - height);
        copy.setColor(fillColor);
        copy.fill(dot);
        copy.dispose();
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        int width = dot.getBounds().width;
        int height = dot.getBounds().height;

        return new Rectangle(point, new Dimension(width, height));
    }

    public void update(double progress) {
        int x = update(progress, from.x, to.x);
        int y = update(progress, from.y, to.y);

        point.x = x;
        point.y = y;
    }

    protected int update(double progress, int from, int to) {
        int distance = to - from;
        int value = (int) Math.round((double) distance * progress);
        value += from;
        if (from < to) {
            value = Math.max(from, Math.min(to, value));
        } else {
            value = Math.max(to, Math.min(from, value));
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

This is a simply object which takes the start and end points and then calculates the position of the object between these points based on the progression.  It can the paint itself when requested.

Now, we just need some way to put it together...

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private Point source;
    private Shape sourceShape;
    private List<Ping> pings;
    private List<Shape> destinations;

    private Color[] colors = new Color[]{Color.BLACK, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, Color.DARK_GRAY, Color.GREEN, Color.MAGENTA, Color.ORANGE, Color.PINK, Color.RED, Color.YELLOW};

    private AnimationEngine engine;

    public TestPane() {
        source = new Point(10, 10);
        sourceShape = new Ellipse2D.Double(source.x - 5, source.y - 5, 10, 10);

        Dimension size = getPreferredSize();

        Random rnd = new Random();
        int quantity = 1 + rnd.nextInt(10);
        pings = new ArrayList<>(quantity);
        destinations = new ArrayList<>(quantity);
        for (int index = 0; index < quantity; index++) {
            int x = 20 + rnd.nextInt(size.width - 25);
            int y = 20 + rnd.nextInt(size.height - 25);

            Point toPoint = new Point(x, y);

            // Create the "ping"
            Color color = colors[rnd.nextInt(colors.length)];
            Ping ping = new Ping(source, toPoint, color);
            pings.add(ping);

            // Create the destination shape...
            Rectangle bounds = ping.getBounds();
            Shape destination = new Ellipse2D.Double(toPoint.x - (bounds.width / 2d), toPoint.y - (bounds.height / 2d), 10, 10);
            destinations.add(destination);
        }

        engine = new AnimationEngine(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        engine.setListener(new AnimationEngine.AnimationEngineListener() {
            @Override
            public void animationEngineTicked(AnimationEngine source, double progress) {
                for (Ping ping : pings) {
                    ping.update(progress);
                }
                repaint();
            }
        });
        engine.start();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        // This is probably overkill, but it will make the output look nicer ;)
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);

        // Lines first, these could be cached
        g2d.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        double fromX = sourceShape.getBounds2D().getCenterX();
        double fromY = sourceShape.getBounds2D().getCenterY();
        for (Shape destination : destinations) {
            double toX = destination.getBounds2D().getCenterX();
            double toY = destination.getBounds2D().getCenterY();
            g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(fromX, fromY, toX, toY));
        }

        // Pings, so they appear above the line, but under the points
        for (Ping ping : pings) {
            ping.paint(this, g2d);
        }

        // Destination and source
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        for (Shape destination : destinations) {
            g2d.fill(destination);
        }

        g2d.fill(sourceShape);

        g2d.dispose();
    }

}
```

Okay, this "looks" complicated, but it's really simple.

- We create a "source" point
- We then create a random number of "targets"
- We then create a animation engine and start it.

The animation engine will then loop through all the `Ping`s and update them based on the current progress value and trigger a new paint pass, which then paints the lines between the source and target points, paints the `Ping`s and then finally the source and all the target points.  Simple.

## What if I want the animation to run at different speeds?

Ah, well, this is much more complicated and requires a more complex animation engine.

Generally speaking, you could establish a concept of something which is "animatable".  This would then be updated by a central "engine" which continuously "ticked" (wasn't itself constrained to duration).

Each "animatable" would then need to make decisions about how it was going to update or report its state and allow other objects to be updated.

In this case, I'd be looking towards a more ready made solution, for example...

- [Super Simple Swing Animation Framework](https://github.com/RustyKnight/SuperSimpleSwingAnimationFramework) - This is an experiment API I wrote, so I'd only consider it a learning point
- [Universal Tween Engine](https://github.com/AurelienRibon/universal-tween-engine)
- [The TimingFramework](https://github.com/akuhtz/timingframework)
- [Trident](https://github.com/kirill-grouchnikov/radiance/blob/master/docs/trident/trident.md)

## Runnable example....

[image: Ping me]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class JavaApplication124 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JavaApplication124();
    }

    public JavaApplication124() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Point source;
        private Shape sourceShape;
        private List<Ping> pings;
        private List<Shape> destinations;

        private Color[] colors = new Color[]{Color.BLACK, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, Color.DARK_GRAY, Color.GREEN, Color.MAGENTA, Color.ORANGE, Color.PINK, Color.RED, Color.YELLOW};

        private AnimationEngine engine;

        public TestPane() {
            source = new Point(10, 10);
            sourceShape = new Ellipse2D.Double(source.x - 5, source.y - 5, 10, 10);

            Dimension size = getPreferredSize();

            Random rnd = new Random();
            int quantity = 1 + rnd.nextInt(10);
            pings = new ArrayList<>(quantity);
            destinations = new ArrayList<>(quantity);
            for (int index = 0; index < quantity; index++) {
                int x = 20 + rnd.nextInt(size.width - 25);
                int y = 20 + rnd.nextInt(size.height - 25);

                Point toPoint = new Point(x, y);

                // Create the "ping"
                Color color = colors[rnd.nextInt(colors.length)];
                Ping ping = new Ping(source, toPoint, color);
                pings.add(ping);

                // Create the destination shape...
                Rectangle bounds = ping.getBounds();
                Shape destination = new Ellipse2D.Double(toPoint.x - (bounds.width / 2d), toPoint.y - (bounds.height / 2d), 10, 10);
                destinations.add(destination);
            }

            engine = new AnimationEngine(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
            engine.setListener(new AnimationEngine.AnimationEngineListener() {
                @Override
                public void animationEngineTicked(AnimationEngine source, double progress) {
                    for (Ping ping : pings) {
                        ping.update(progress);
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            engine.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            // This is probably overkill, but it will make the output look nicer ;)
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);

            // Lines first, these could be cached
            g2d.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            double fromX = sourceShape.getBounds2D().getCenterX();
            double fromY = sourceShape.getBounds2D().getCenterY();
            for (Shape destination : destinations) {
                double toX = destination.getBounds2D().getCenterX();
                double toY = destination.getBounds2D().getCenterY();
                g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(fromX, fromY, toX, toY));
            }

            // Pings, so they appear above the line, but under the points
            for (Ping ping : pings) {
                ping.paint(this, g2d);
            }

            // Destination and source
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            for (Shape destination : destinations) {
                g2d.fill(destination);
            }

            g2d.fill(sourceShape);

            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

    // Self contained, duration based, animation engine...
    public static class AnimationEngine {

        private Instant startTime;
        private Duration duration;

        private Timer timer;

        private AnimationEngineListener listener;

        public AnimationEngine(Duration duration) {
            this.duration = duration;
        }

        public void start() {
            if (timer != null) {
                return;
            }
            startTime = null;
            timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    tick();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        public void stop() {
            timer.stop();
            timer = null;
            startTime = null;
        }

        public void setListener(AnimationEngineListener listener) {
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        public AnimationEngineListener getListener() {
            return listener;
        }

        public Duration getDuration() {
            return duration;
        }

        public double getRawProgress() {
            if (startTime == null) {
                return 0.0;
            }
            Duration duration = getDuration();
            Duration runningTime = Duration.between(startTime, Instant.now());
            double progress = (runningTime.toMillis() / (double) duration.toMillis());

            return Math.min(1.0, Math.max(0.0, progress));
        }

        protected void tick() {
            if (startTime == null) {
                startTime = Instant.now();
            }
            double rawProgress = getRawProgress();
            if (rawProgress >= 1.0) {
                rawProgress = 1.0;
            }

            AnimationEngineListener listener = getListener();
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.animationEngineTicked(this, rawProgress);
            }

            // This is done so if you wish to expand the 
            // animation listener to include start/stop events
            // this won't interfer with the tick event
            if (rawProgress >= 1.0) {
                rawProgress = 1.0;
                stop();
            }
        }

        public static interface AnimationEngineListener {

            public void animationEngineTicked(AnimationEngine source, double progress);
        }
    }

    public class Ping {

        private Point point;
        private Point from;
        private Point to;
        private Color fillColor;

        private Shape dot;

        public Ping(Point from, Point to, Color fillColor) {
            this.from = from;
            this.to = to;
            this.fillColor = fillColor;
            point = new Point(from);

            dot = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 6, 6);
        }

        public void paint(Container parent, Graphics2D g2d) {
            Graphics2D copy = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();
            int width = dot.getBounds().width / 2;
            int height = dot.getBounds().height / 2;
            copy.translate(point.x - width, point.y - height);
            copy.setColor(fillColor);
            copy.fill(dot);
            copy.dispose();
        }

        public Rectangle getBounds() {
            int width = dot.getBounds().width;
            int height = dot.getBounds().height;

            return new Rectangle(point, new Dimension(width, height));
        }

        public void update(double progress) {
            int x = update(progress, from.x, to.x);
            int y = update(progress, from.y, to.y);

            point.x = x;
            point.y = y;
        }

        protected int update(double progress, int from, int to) {
            int distance = to - from;
            int value = (int) Math.round((double) distance * progress);
            value += from;
            if (from < to) {
                value = Math.max(from, Math.min(to, value));
            } else {
                value = Math.max(to, Math.min(from, value));
            }

            return value;
        }
    }

}
```

## Isn't there something simpler

As I said, good animation, is hard.  It takes a lot of effort and planning to do well. I've not even talked about easement, chained or blending algorithms, so trust me when I say, this is actually a simple, reusable solution

Don't believe me, check out [JButton hover animation in Java Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51903228/jbutton-hover-animation-in-java-swing/51904555#51904555)

Answer (score -2):

Try this one :

```
public class Player extends Thread {
 private  Graphics graphic;
 private Graphics2D g2;
 private int x;
 private int y;
 private DrawPanel panel;
 private numberOfIteration=5;
 private currentNumberOfIteration=0;
    public Player(int x, int y,DrawPanel panel) 
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.panel = panel;
        graphic = panel.getGraphics();
        g2 = (Graphics2D) graphic;
        g2.fillOval( column,row, 10, 10);
    }
    public Player(int x, int y,DrawPanel panel,int numberOfIteration) 
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.panel = panel;
        this.numberOfIteration=numberOfIterarion;
        graphic = panel.getGraphics();
        g2 = (Graphics2D) graphic;
        g2.fillOval( column,row, 10, 10);
    }
    public void run()
    {
     //startAnimation(this.x,this.y,destination.x,destination.y)
        currentNumberOfIteration=(++currentNumberOfIteration)%numberOfIteration;
        currentX=(int)((destinationX*currentNumberOfIteration+this.x)/(currentNumberOfIteration+1));
        currentY=(int)((destinationY*currentNumberOfIteration+this.y)/(currentNumberOfIteration+1));
        g2.fillOval( currentX,currentY, 10, 10);

    }
}
```

I don't see any declaration part of `destinationX` and `destinationY`.

Comment: ah sorry,with destination I meant only  the  coordinates(int x,int y)  of arrival;  I tried and if I didn't make mistakes your code I just "spawn" another point, I wanted to do a little animation

Comment: Clear previous ... See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30005776/10305444) thread