# Draw 2D graphics on a widget? Please clear this example from Head First Java book for me

Tags: java, swing

So far the book has been mostly clear and consistent, on occasions i had to go back and reread but in this example i am really stuck, no matter how much i reread i just don't get it. It's either something missed out in the book or i am missing the whole point. So please if you can clear this up for me, it is bugging me immensely and i don't want to continue to read the book without getting this right.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyDrawPanel pan = new MyDrawPanel();
        pan.go();
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2; // this was not mentioned in the book, but i had to put it to get rid of the warning the compiler gives without it (i googled it)

    public void go() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
    // In the book it's mentioned that you never call this method yourself (i don't quite get it how that works...)
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.orange);
        g.fillRect(20,50,100,100);
    }

}
```

The code above compiles and runs just fine but nothing happens.

I tried to instantiate a Graphics object and play around but apparently the Graphics class in an abstract one..

Thank you!

edit: I have the 2nd edition of the book, so you can turn to page 364 chapter 12 if you have it as well (the code where i draw the JFrame is from the previous example - and i think that the paintComponent() method example just adds to the previous example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main problem is that you never add instance of `MyDrawPanel` to frame you created in `go()` method, so it remains empty.

One way to fix it is to explicitly add current (`this`) instance of `MyDrawPanel` in `go` method like

```
public void go() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300,300);
    frame.add(this);       //  <-- add this line, 
                           //  you can also use frame.setContentPane(this)
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. and this was definitely left out in the book :/ (edit: the book actually never explained exactly what "this" means yet..)

Comment: `this` inside method represents object on which method was invoked. So if we execute code like `someInstance.method()` then from inside `method()` `this` will hold same reference as `someInstance`. So here since we invoked `pan.go();` inside `go()` method `this` returns same reference as `pan` which holds `MyDrawPanel` instance, which allows us to add this panel to frame via `frame.add(this);`.

Comment: @masky007 But there are also other meanings of `this` depending on context. Like inside constructor we can use it like `this(argument1, argument2)` to invoke code from another constructor of same class.

Answer (score 1):

You always should call `super.paintComponent(g);`

Also, you should choose a different design to create your frames and panels. Personally I would use this:

```
public class MyGui extends JFrame {
    public MyGui() {
        DrawPanel myDrawPanel = new DrawPanel();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.add(myDrawPanel);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}

public class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {
    public MyDrawPanel() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.orange);
        g.fillRect(20,50,100,100);
    }
}
```

Useful answer to understand what `super.paintComponent(g)` does: [What does super.paintComponent(g) do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28724609/what-does-super-paintcomponentg-do)

Comment: Prefer composition over inheritance, don't extend frame if you don't really have to. More info: [Extends JFrame vs. creating it inside the program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003802/extends-jframe-vs-creating-it-inside-the-program)

Comment: @Pshemo interesting, this is how they learned it to me at university. Thanks!