# How would I draw on a JPanel to then be shown on a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, nullpointerexception, jpanel

I've tried to research how Java's 2D rendering works, but I could never understand it. Here is the code in my main class:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main{

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("JFrame testing");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Frame panel = new Frame();
        frame.add(panel);
    }
}
```

And then here is for the `JPanel` class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Frame extends JPanel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Frame() {
        Graphics g = this.getGraphics();
        g.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
        this.paintComponent(g);
    }
}
```

I am also getting this exception, but I'm not sure what it means:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Frame.<init>(Frame.java:10)
    at Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

I'm basically just trying to draw a rectangle onto a panel to be shown on the frame I've created. I've heard about the `paintComponent` method, but I also don't fully understand that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **Never** use `getGraphics()` of a Component.

Try below code

```
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
        //this.paintComponent(g);
    }
```

**Edit**

> "*why is super.paintComponent(g); called again inside the method?*"

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) of `paintComponent` says it pretty well:

> if you do not invoker super's implementation you must honor the opaque
>   property, that is if this component is opaque, you must completely
>   fill in the background in a non-opaque color. If you do not honor the
>   opaque property you will likely see visual artifacts.

Comment: Thank you, but do you mind explaining what this does because I'm not really sure what the paintComponent method does.

Comment: when your project running, `paintComponent` function will be called by passing in the Graphics parameter as a graphics context onto which you can draw.

Comment: So I learned that paintComponent is overriding a Jcomponent object, but why is `super.paintComponent(g);` called again inside the method?

Comment: You may go through the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

Comment: Sorry I just updated my comment to:

So I learned that paintComponent is overriding a Jcomponent object, but why is `super.paintComponent(g);` called again inside the method? I just tried without that and it still worked, so what's the point in including it?

Comment: Ok, thanks for all your help, it really helped me out.

Comment: you can find more answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28724609/what-does-super-paintcomponentg-do